# PostgreSQL - Efficiently maintaining ranking of items

Tags: sql, postgresql, ranking

My application has a large number (~100K and growing) of items that are ranked based on their score. Only a small number (~100) of items are active and have changing scores at a given time, and they need to be alerted of their rank changes in real-time (synchronously). Typically, the score of active items slowly increases, but sometimes it jumps either up or down.

My current solution is to keep all of the items' scores in RAM. Whenever I increase the score of a single item, I check if that item's score is higher than the item in front of it and swap until it's back in sorted order. For the big jumps, I do a binary search, reinsert the item, and update the ranks for every item between the starting and ending position. If their ranks are changed at any point, I notify any active items of their new ranks.

Now my question is: Is there any way to efficiently maintain ranks like this in an SQL database? (I'm currently using PostgreSQL.) I know that a database will never be able to beat my current, highly specialized, method, but I'd gladly sacrifice a tiny bit of efficiency as long as it's still relatively fast. I now have other interfaces that want to access the same rank data, but they can't when it's hidden inside my main application which doesn't want to be bothered. Note: the other interfaces do not need real-time data, they'd be OK with a few minutes of inaccuracy.

Thoughts:

- I'm aware that I can use dense_sort() to generate the rankings on the fly. This query currently takes 80ms on my table, so it's far too slow to be usable in the real-time part of application.
- Are there are any PostgreSQL plugins or alternate software existing that address this sort of problem? It seems like it might be a common one.
- Two half-solutions: 1. Update the scores in the database periodically and allow other interfaces to use the slow dense_sort() (possibly on a materialized view) to get ranks of items, or 2. keep the ranks in the database as well, and periodically update them from my main application so the other interfaces can select them directly.

Any pointers, advice, or tips about existing solutions that would help me with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have too many simulataneous writes for a single row to handle? If not than a simple `SELECT ... rank() OVER (PARTITION BY score) FROM table` should do the trick

Comment: Just for clarity, can you provide table definitions with example data? SQLFiddle would be great :) Also, do you have an index on your score column?

Comment: This works: `select ... dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC)` but it takes 80 ms, so it's too slow to use in my main application, which is latency-sensitive. This query re-orders everything every time, whereas my algorithm keeps things sorted as they are changed.

Comment: I tried adding an index on the score column but it seems to make absolutely no difference in query time.

Comment: 80 **milli** seconds is *far* too slow? Wow, you have some really challenging performance requirements

Comment: When 80 milliseconds is considered too slow, you really have to optimize your hardware, OS, database configuration, datamodel, indexes and queries. A database can be really fast, but what are your requirements and limitations?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be below 5 or 10ms and I'd like to be cheap and make good use of my processing power. My current solution is extremely fast -- sub millisecond. Something tells me I'm simply not going to get this speed with a relational database because it's too naive for this type of problem. Since my application is currently single-threaded, 80ms x 100 items x approximately 1 update every 3 seconds would grind things to a halt. Even if fixed that, 80ms extra delay is quite bad... network delay is typically less than that and my application adds ~1-20 ms of processing delay already. Thx.

Comment: For a web application 80ms is a lot, for simple view requests that should be the total load time. When the load time increases the activity on a website drastically reduces.

Comment: Can you show the output of an explain analyse of the query you tried to use? Including limits and order by since that changes the query plan as well.

Comment: You could maintain a denormalized `score=>rank` table. The cost of maintaining it depending on how dense the ranks are. Keep in mind that frequently updating a large number of rows is the worst scenario for postgres. But if the table is small your current code could refresh it every few minutes.